# AngularJS Ошибка TypeError: this is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular2, angular5

Все проекты реализованные на Angular (Angular 5.2.9) (работаю в webstorm) нормально работают при выполнении компанды ng serve (npm run start) на запустившимся командой сервере. Но после сборки командой "ng build --prod" и загрузки полученных файлов в каталог Apache и открытии странички выдаётся собственно ошибка и разработанный модуль не загружается. Подскажите, как быть?

Раскрывая ошибку вижу следующее:

```
e()
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
e/<()
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
e()
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
.WT6e/</U</e.prototype.get()
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
Ge/</<()
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
Ge/<()
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
Ge/<()
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
.x35b()
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
t()
inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1
[0]()
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
t()
inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1
window.webpackJsonp()
inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1
<анонимная>
main.16bd2dbbc06007f15324.bundle.js:1
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить подключаемый `angular.min.js` на `angular.js`

Comment: А если запустить на `Apache` не минифицированный проект? Попробуйте выполнить `ng build` без `--prod`. Закиньте на сервер, по идеи будет более информативная ошибка. Наперед могу сказать, что скорее всего проблема с путями будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём случае проблема заключалась в старой версии браузера Firefox.